# How to mix Poster-grid / Row-list types in one screen using brightscript and Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

How can I use multiple screen types on the same screen? For example, how can I show the PosterGrid on top and then the Rowlist at the bottom..?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the both and pass focus in the `onKeyEvent` function.
Both PosterGrid and RowList are not Screens, so you can place 'em anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's Displayed Both Components successfully using a PanelSet. But PanelSet does not maintain Focus in RowList. It only maintains Focus on **PanelNode Classes**. you can use two PosterGrid as a GridPanel in one screen. That means you create a two-child and every child has a GridPanel. Here the example [SlidingPanel](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/sliding-panels-nodes/overview.md). You use another GridPanel instead of ListPanel.